# mysql, how to delete selected data from database?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table like this:
`table 1`

```
    id  time
122639  1315510027
122639  1315510026
122639  1315510027
122639  1315510030
122640  1315510366
```

how can i make a query that deletes everything but `122640  1315510366` ? even if i have to use php

any ideas?

Thsnks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id != 122640;

Note: if you have other entries with that ID, you'll need to do id != 122640 AND time != 1315510366;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: I actually thought it was until I submitted my answer and noticed that there were multiple 122639 items.  And it could be an id for an event and the time could be the time that event occurred.  (In which case I would hope there's either a synthetic primary key or that there's one on id and time.)